# Font from origin 'https://storage.googleapis.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-app-engine, flask, cors

**Background**

- I am running Google App Engine with Python using Flask.
- I am calling certain web assets in Google Cloud Storage buckets via https://storage.googleapis.com/*

I can verify the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`header is being set on the request, as per the evidence below.

[image]

**Problem**

How is it then that I still get the following error in my browser (chrome).

> Font from origin 'https://storage.googleapis.com' has been blocked
>   from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

**Code**

I am using the [Flask Snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/) "Decorator for the HTTP Access Control", to set origins as below:

```
@admin_articles_routes.route('/xxx/xxx/xxx-xx')
@crossdomain(origin="*")
@authenticate_admin
def edit_article():
```

-------- Edit-----------

```
Curl response
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:App-Engine vinay$ curl -version http://localhost:8080/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx-xxxx?ID=ahlkZXZ-Y2ZjLW1lbGJvdXJuZS13ZWJzaXRlcjbGUYgICAgICAgAoM
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /xxx/xxxx/xxxx-xxxxx?ID=ahlkZXZ-Y2ZjLW1lbGJvdXJuZS13ZWJzaXRlcjELEgdBcnRpY2xlIhBBcnRpY2xlR3JhZHBhS2V5DAsSB0FydGljbGUYgICAgICAgAoM HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Referer: rsion
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< access-control-max-age: 21600
< location: http://localhost:8080/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxx-xxxxx%3FID%3DahlkZXZ-Y2ZjLW1lbGJvdXJuZS13ZWJzbGUYgICAgICAgAoM
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-methods: HEAD, GET
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Length: 575
< Server: Development/2.0
```

Comment: I see `access-control-allow-origin` but not `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: The snippet code has the value in caps.        h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin

Comment: so you mean that this image of response with headers is fake? can you show a real one instead then?

Comment: I don't think its fake. I think its lower case. The codebase has the header in camel case.

Comment: but on image it's not in camel case, is it real image with real headers or not?

Comment: Yes it is. I have verified it via curl

Comment: ok, then put curl response instead. current image is misleading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90687/discussion-between-vinay-joseph-and-igor-artamonov).

Comment: curl has been added.

Comment: As you see, you curl show lowercase fields. But I just found in RFC that *field names a case-insensitive*. I didn't know that. So you can ignore my comments, sorry about this. Also, Chrome doesn't support `localhost` for `CORS`, but there should be different error message at this case

Comment: The CORS headers need to be on the font URL, not that of the page that's loading it.

Comment: As this is an old post without an answer, I ask that you post the solution that worked for you as an official answer. If Greg's previous solution did not work for you, and you are still seeing the issue, I ask that you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a [Community Wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) of the last answer provided by Greg.*

The [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simple_example) `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be returned by the host server that is accepting the request, as it is the server that sets the rules for who can access its own resources.

The CORS `OPTIONS` [preflight headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Preflight_example) are to be set by the requester who is making the request, so that it properly identifies itself to the host server.

For more information, you can see this additional [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work).